# Removing every 3rd and 4th row in a dataframe between certain row numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very long dataframe that looks like this (though rather than numbers the column day is populated with dates):

```
    df <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("date", times = 100)),
             Day = c(1:100))
```

There is a period of time in the middle of my df where I would like to remove the third and fourth of every 4 rows, say from row 50 to 70, so it would end up looking like this:

```
  df <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("date", times = 80)),
             Date = c(1:52,55,56,59,60,63,64,67,68,71:90))
```

Is there a way of doing this without manually naming every row index I would like to remove? Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Is the `Date` column consecutive without any gaps in the original data? Please reduce your toy data, e.g. 20 rows and relevant range from 5 to 15.

Comment: Yes an emphasis on *minimal* in minimal reproducible example. Great question though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus operator can be useful for this kind of thing.

```r
idx <- seq(nrow(df))
idx <- idx[idx < 51 | (idx + 1) %% 4 < 2 | idx > 70]
df <- df[idx, ]
```

Or alternatively, using a negative index:

```r
idx <- 51:70
idx <- idx[(idx + 1) %% 4 > 1]
df <- df[-idx, ]
```

Result from either approach:

```
#> df[45:75, ]
   Type Day
45 date  45
46 date  46
47 date  47
48 date  48
49 date  49
50 date  50
51 date  51
52 date  52
55 date  55
56 date  56
59 date  59
60 date  60
63 date  63
64 date  64
67 date  67
68 date  68
71 date  71
72 date  72
73 date  73
74 date  74
75 date  75
76 date  76
77 date  77
78 date  78
79 date  79
80 date  80
81 date  81
82 date  82
83 date  83
84 date  84
85 date  85
```

Comment: FWIW, this is also very fast (nearly 3x faster than mine).

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer the solution given by @zephryl here is another option where you construct the row indices you want to remove using the `by` argument of `seq`:

```r
df[-unlist(lapply(3:4, \(x) seq(50, 70, x)[-1])),]
```

Comment: This is great. Though would prefer using the vectorized function `sequence` instead of `unlist+lapply+seq` ie in your case `sequence((70-50)/3:4, 50+3:4, 3:4)`

Comment: Not really its just rewriting this same answer. Perhaps you could edit and add it as another option